# Python3 printing user input with strings on a new line in a video game

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

Python beginner here, couple months in, still confused and still having mayjor impostor syndrome.

I was playing some Diablo2 Resurrected and while i played i was imagining code in my mind, especially when i used spells on my mage like thunderbolt which does 1-114 damage on my current level ;)

So i alt-tabbed and wrote this code:

```
import random

#For the random thunderbolt spell damage
thunderbolt_damage = random.randint(1,114)

#Asking for user input
mouse_clicks = int(input("How often do you want to click to use thunderbolt? "))


def thunder_spell():
    
    mana = 120
    '''Mana at my current level in Diablo2'''
    while mouse_clicks > 0:
        mana += mouse_clicks * -9 
        break
    
    print("You have " + str(mana) + " Mana left")
    

   
            
    print("Your thunderbolt just did " + str(thunderbolt_damage) + " damage") 
    
    

thunder_spell()
```

Problems: I want to be able to print the number of times that i click with the mouse and display the random damage each time, on a new line. I tried several things but nothing worked. I was running into errors. I think it could be done with a for loop but i don't know how. I learned using codecademy only mostly.

Comment: I've removed the [tag:pygame] tag. The [tag:pygame] tag addresses the [PyGame](https://www.pygame.org/news) library, but is not intended for a game written in Python.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random


thunderbolt_damage = random.randint(1,114)

#Asking for user input
mouse_clicks = int(input("How often do you want to click to use thunderbolt? "))
mana = 120

def thunder_spell(mana):

    for i in range(0, mouse_clicks):
        mana -= 9
        #For the random thunderbolt spell damage
        thunderbolt_damage = random.randint(1,114)
        print("Your thunderbolt just did " + str(thunderbolt_damage) + " damage")
    return mana
print("You have " + str(thunder_spell(mana)) + " Mana left")
```

If I understand what you are asking for, I believe this will work

Comment: thanks, yeah that works. i can learn from that!